# IP Ban for specific instance in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-ec2-instance-connect

MY IP is blocked  while trying to access my Instance using SSH and i made some password mistakes multiple times.

now I'm always getting "Connection timed out"  when trying to connect.

But i can still access the other instance but not this one.

also i can't access the websites domains in that instance (ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT) so i have to use another internet connection just to access them or maybe vpn and TOR browser ..

Iv'e been searching around on how to fix it or where to remove my IP from block list but can't find anything .. can anyone help me here?   Thanks ..

Comment: "IP from block list" what list? Your own firewall on your pc, security group, firewalls on ec2 instances? Sadly your question is not clear.

Comment: @Marcin  . sorry .  blocked from ec2 instance .. 

im sure my IP is ban because when using different internet i can access it just fine.. 
 so my problem is where can i UNBAN or remove my IP from the block list. cause i can't find it.. 

also i place my IP in security groups but nothing works .. 


NOTE:  i have 3 instance i can access the 2 just fine but not this one where i have made the password mistakes ..

Comment: Do you have software like fail2ban on the instance? Does ‘iptables -F‘ change anything?

Comment: Can you SSH to this instance from _another_ IP? Generally AWS instances are installed without firewall service running (what OS are you running?). if you _can_ - check `firewalld` service and fail2ban - these are the only 2 that might block IP... but seems like you hae a different problem

Comment: @felix  Yes .. i can SSH to the instance using another IP ..  let me try that.. thanks .. Also im using UBUNTU OS

Comment: Standard AWS Ubuntu doesn't enable firewall either. Doublecheck your security rules - that is the main AWS firewall... But of course, it doesn't add rules *automatically* - somebody must have added them manually!

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
aws ssm start-session --target i-abcd12345678
```